# SAS Enterprise 5.1 Entering variable values via a GUI

Tags: user-interface, sas, user-experience

I have several programs in SAS for database access and I was asked if I can put a GUI on top so that some "Analysts" can also use my programs without using code. I know this can be done in SAS. But how?

They basically want to change variables like start_date or other parameters and then hit a run button :-)

Comment: Thanks RamB. I found our it is possible with simple "Stored Processes". Now they can use it :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with prompts.
Right click your code in Enterprise Guide, then Properties.

You will then need to go to the prompt manager from there, and after creating the fields, you have to add them to your code.

There is a way to create this via base language, but I cannot test it, since it's not supported in my SAS environment.

Edit: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291000/how-to-add-input-box-to-sas-sql-query-which-ask-user-about-parameter/34291391#34291391) question has an example of how to do it with BASE. Written by SMW.